# REST resource for checking if a resource has existing subresources

Tags: rest

My application provides the following resource:

```
GET /user/:id/orders
```

As commonly used, this returns a list of all the user's orders.

Now, a client wants to check if a user has any orders at all without actually getting the complete list.

My current approach looks like this:

```
GET /user/:id/orders/exist
```

But it looks kind of odd to me.

Is there a more "standard" way of designing this? In the end, this resource only needs to return the information:

- yes, user has orders
- no, user doesn't have any orders

Comment: Depending on your design, you could either return a `404 Not Found` on requesting `GET /users/:id/orders` for no orders or simply return a response with no links to concrete orders in the payload. If your collection-resource supports filtering and paging you could also use these to limit the number or returned items in case there are more orders available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will see in some API is the notion of a resource that exists (204) or does not exist (404).

But I really don't recommend that: saving a few bytes in your representation of the resource doesn't help very much when you are already sending a response-line and a bunch of HTTP headers.

---

Your "resource model" can be anything you want.

> The REST interface is designed to be efficient for large-grain hypermedia data transfer, optimizing for the common case of the Web, but resulting in an interface that is not optimal for other forms of architectural interaction -- [Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5)

So you *can* create fine grained resources if you like; but there are can be consequences to that.  "Tradeoffs" are a thing.

Resources are generalizations of "documents"; if it makes sense to have a report that is just a count of the number of orders, or a statement that the number of orders is greater than zero, or whatever, then that report can certainly be a resource in your resource model.

If you know what the report is, then you might be able to guess at a name for the report, and from there to a spelling for it.

There's no particular reason that the report identifier has to be part of the /user hierarchy; the machines don't care what spelling conventions you use.

```
/user/:id/orders/report
/user/:id/orders-report
/user/:id/report
/report/:id
/report?user=:id
/report/user=:id
```

Those are all *fine*; choose whichever variation is appropriate to your local conventions.

---

Note that you want to be aware of [caching](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4) - when you have information in two different resources, it is easy for the client's locally cached copies to contradict each other (report says that there are orders, but the orders list is empty; or the other way around).  As far as REST, and general purpose components are concerned, different resources are *different*, and vary independently of each other.

In the large grained world, you don't have that problem so often, because you throw the kitchen sink into a single resource; as long as its produced representations are internally consistent, the cached copies will be as well.